# If statement to remap values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create an if statement that populates the tool type column with  `Legal` if the Pay Category column is `Expense`.

However, it is flaging everything that contains `Legal` as `Legal`, regardless of Pay Category.

```
test={"Pay Category":["Indemnity","Indemnity","Indemnity","Indemnity","Expense","Expense","Expense","Medical"],"Description of Payment":["Legal","Legal","Legal","Legal","Legal","Legal","Frog","Legal",]}
test=pd.DataFrame(test)

test["Tool Type"]=""
if (test["Pay Category"]=="Medical") is not False: 
test["Tool Type"][test["Description of Payment"].str.contains("Pharmacy|Prescription|RX",case=False)]="Pharmacy"

if (test["Pay Category"]=='Expense') is not False:
test["Tool Type"][test["Description of Payment"].str.contains("Legal|Attorney|Court|Defense",case=False)]="Legal"
```

My understanding is, `if (test["Pay Category"]=='Expense') is not False:` is a boolean value which is either `True or False`, it should only execute the if statement if the criteria " is not False" is met. What am I missing?

Brandon

Comment: Searching through the description of payment column, for those key words, which all get mapped to Legal in the tool type column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need add conditions and chain them with `&` (`and`):

```
test["Tool Type"]=""
m1 = test["Description of Payment"].str.contains("Pharmacy|Prescription|RX",case=False)
m2 = test["Pay Category"]=="Medical"

m3 = test["Description of Payment"].str.contains("Legal|Attorney|Court|Defense",case=False)
m4 = test["Pay Category"]=="Expense"

test.loc[m1 & m2, "Tool Type"]="Pharmacy"
test.loc[m3 & m4, "Tool Type"]="Legal"
print (test)
  Description of Payment Pay Category Tool Type
0                  Legal    Indemnity          
1                  Legal    Indemnity          
2                  Legal    Indemnity          
3                  Legal    Indemnity          
4                  Legal      Expense     Legal
5                  Legal      Expense     Legal
6                   Frog      Expense          
7                  Legal      Medical
```

Another solution with double [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
test['Tool Type'] = np.where(m1 & m2, 'Pharmacy',
                    np.where(m3 & m4, 'Legal', ''))
print (test)
  Description of Payment Pay Category Tool Type
0                  Legal    Indemnity          
1                  Legal    Indemnity          
2                  Legal    Indemnity          
3                  Legal    Indemnity          
4                  Legal      Expense     Legal
5                  Legal      Expense     Legal
6                   Frog      Expense          
7                  Legal      Medical
```

EDIT: Very nice solution with [`unutbu`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576329/if-statement-to-remap-values/45576400?noredirect=1#comment78114087_45576400) comment is use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
test['Tool Type']  = np.select([(m1 & m2), (m3 & m4)], ['Pharmacy', 'Legal'], default='')
print (test)
  Description of Payment Pay Category Tool Type
0                  Legal    Indemnity          
1                  Legal    Indemnity          
2                  Legal    Indemnity          
3                  Legal    Indemnity          
4                  Legal      Expense     Legal
5                  Legal      Expense     Legal
6                   Frog      Expense          
7                  Legal      Medical
```

Comment: Great solution, can you possibly clarify where I went wrong in my attempt?

Comment: I think there is problem you working with arrays, not with scalars. so if need some conditions, working with arrays of `True` and `False` values. So need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and chaning conditions.

Comment: Good luck, nice day!

Comment: You could compress multiple `np.where`s into one [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html): e.g. `np.select([(m1 & m2), (m3 & m4)], ['Pharmacy', 'Legal'], default='')`.

Comment: @unutbu - Thank you, it is nice.